# Appending to setParameters in CreateQueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying this

```
$results = this->get('doctrine')->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('x.a, x.b')
        ->from('mytable', 'x');

$results->where('AND x.d = :d');

if ('All' == $my_var) {
    $results->andWhere('x.a IN (:my_var)')
}

$results->setParameters(
    array(
        'd' => $var_d,
    )
);
```

Now I want to append `setParameters` and add `('my_var' => $my_var)` when `('All' == $my_var)`, is it poosible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but make sure to use `setParameter` instead of `setParameters` in this case, because `setParameters` ignore prior parameters settings.

**Wrong example:**

```
$qb->where('entity.foo = :foo');
$qb->setParameter('foo', $foo); // this param will be ignored after setParameters is called.
// ...
$qb->andWhere('entity.bar = :bar AND entity.baz = :baz')
$qb->setParameters(array('bar' => $bar, 'baz' => $baz)); // wrong statement.

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This throw a `QueryException` message: `Too few parameters: the query defines 3 parameters but you only bound 2`.

**Good example:**

```
$qb->where('entity.foo = :foo');
$qb->setParameter('foo', $foo);
// ...
$qb->andWhere('entity.bar = :bar AND entity.baz = :baz')
$qb->setParameter('bar', $bar);
$qb->setParameter('baz', $baz);

// or setting all parameters to end
$qb->setParameters(array('foo' => $foo, 'bar' => $bar, 'baz' => $baz)); 

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

**In your case:**

```
$results = this->get('doctrine')->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('x.a, x.b')
    ->from('mytable', 'x');

$results->where('x.d = :d')->setParameter('d', $var_d);

if ('All' === $my_var) {
    $results->andWhere('x.a IN (:my_var)')->setParameter('my_var', $my_var);
}
```

**Note:** In your code `$results->where('AND x.d = :d');` and remember that using `where`/`andWhere` statements they already adds `AND` to sql query resultant.

Answer (score 0):

what about this....

```
if ('All'== $my_var) {
     // your total query with parameter
} else{
    //query code and skip parameter
}
```